# Transferring raster band features to another raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I have one raster layer containing a band that indicates the land type of a random sample of pixels and another raster containing NDVI, VV, and VH values. The first raster has fewer pixels than the second, hence there are areas where the single bands of this layer would show "no data".

How would I go about transferring band values from pixels from the second raster to the first where there are actually pixels in the first raster (the single band has a value)?

A similar question to mine, [Extracting value from one raster to another raster using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342528), suggested using the raster calculator with the expression "layer1"*"layer2", but this only returns one band that seems to have just multiplied the two bands from the input rasters. I am a beginner when it comes to using QGIS, and especially to using the raster calculator, hence I am having trouble finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

To use the first raster (let me call it `Raster1`) as the base layer to accommodate the values from the second one (`Raster2`), you can use **Create Constant Raster Layer** tool in the QGIS `Processing Toolbox > Raster Creation`.

[image]

(1) Click on the small ellipsis <kbd>...</kbd> button and set the `Raster1` as the basis for the extent calculation.

(2) Pixel size should be the cell size of the `Raster1` layer. Leave the `Constant value` at the default `1.0` which initializes the cell value.

(3) Click on `Run` and you will get a new layer (`'Constant'`).

(4) Start **Raster Calculator**

[image]

(5)  Click and highlight the `Constant@1` (**1**) then click on <kbd>Selected Layer Extent</kbd> button (**2**).

(6) Name the output file path and file name (**3**).

(7) Input the equation `"Constant@1" * "Raster2@1"` (**4**) and click on `OK` to run.

[image]

Then the values from the `Raster2` (lower left) will be copied across to the `Raster1` (upper right) grid system. (see the `Output` layer which is shown in grey scale).